# Push notifications using Grease/TamperMonkey userscripts?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to push notifications or updates out through my userscript. It's coded in Javascript, like all userscripts.

The only thing I have thought about, is getting a server which would host my file. Then the userscript would check if that file has been changed, and if it has, then display the new message. Basically allowing me to push out messages.

Is there a way to do that? Push notifications or updates without using a server, because that would be too much. I use http://userscripts.org/ for hosting my userscripts, but I haven't been able to find any way of pushing out notifications.

Comment: How many are you trying to push to and how much do you trust them?

Comment: Are you looking to jsut update your own script? If so, it's a built in feature of GreaseMonkey for quite some time now. Unless there was some change I'm not aware of:
http://www.greasespot.net/2012/02/automatic-script-updates-come-to.html